# fbjs naming collision error in react-packager followed by keyMirror resolve error

Tags: react-native

After upgrading my react-native project to `0.21.0`, I encountered this error while running react-packager:

`Failed to build DependencyGraph: Naming collision detected: /Users/xxxxxxxx/node_modules/react/node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js collides with /Users/xxxxxxx/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js`

I've tried [deleting all instances of `fbjs`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5467#issuecomment-174086678) and cleaning the caches, as well as installing my dependencies with `npm3`, but this results in a module resolve error:

`Unable to resolve module keyMirror from /Users/xxxxxxx/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/MessageQueue.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/node_modules/keyMirror and its parent directories`

It suggests to reset the cache and reinstall node_modules, but this does not resolve the issue.

My `package.json`:

`{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@exponent/react-native-navigator": "^0.4.2",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native": "^0.21.0",
    "react-native-action-button": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-audio": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-blur": "^0.7.7",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-lightbox": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-search-bar": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.16.1"
  }
}`

I have doubts that starting a fresh project will fix this, as it's clearly related to dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this with this script:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5467#issuecomment-187873411

```
'use strict';

const blacklist = require('react-native/packager/blacklist');

var config = [
  /{root folder name}\/node_modules\/.+\/node_modules\/fbjs\/.*/
]

module.exports = {
  getBlacklistRE() {
    return blacklist('', config);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this tip left by [jrichardlai commented on Jan 22](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5467#issuecomment-174086678)

> For people that are still facing this issue, a temporary can be to add
>   fbjs as a dependency in your package.json, and then run a script in
>   postinstall to remove the extra fbjs
>   https://gist.github.com/jrichardlai/a6a36352e1b98eb2946a

Which links to the gist as such...

```
find ./node_modules -type d -name fbjs -and -not -path ./node_modules/fbjs -print -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

Comment: Yup, which leads to the keymirror error  after trying that very solution I linked

Comment: Then I suggest adding your voice to the related conversation on github.

Comment: After looking at some more issues, I found the solution to hush the keyMirror error.